# Is it possiable to add one or more sections in html

Tags: html, css

i am using the simple html page in that page i am displaying the departments along with sections. i tried to add the SectionF1.1 and SectionF1.2 under SectionF1 in Department F.How can achieve this please Help me!!

Comment: Here is my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/n5kv83xo/2/

Comment: Did you write the css yourself? There are specific css instructions for the different levels, and for the directly nested nodes of the department. If you Want sublevels for the sections, you should write additional css for that.

Comment: no i did not write the css i am not familer to css,can you please help @ Justus Romijn

Comment: You should see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) @arjun

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood what you want, here's a working version.

**In HTML:** Add a 'has-child' class or some other class name to your section if it has sub-sections. Then immediately after that element add a sub-section element like so:

```
<li class="section has-child"><a href="#"><span>Section F1</span></a></li>

<ul class="section sub-section">
    <li>F1.1</li>
    <li>F1.2</li>
    <li>F1.3</li>
</ul>
```

**In jQuery:** Replace your current code with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').siblings('.sections').hide();
    $('.sub-section').hide();
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.sections').toggle();
    });

    $('.has-child').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.sub-section').toggle();
    })
});
```

The sub-section elements do not have any styling currently, but the functionality works.

**Edit:** jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/n5kv83xo/3/

Comment: can you please update change in fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/n5kv83xo/2/ @Zentryn